# Adding line showing percent difference ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am trying to add a line to my bar graph showing the % difference of the years. I was trying to create a function:

```
year_pct_change <- function(x) {
  x <- x[order(x$Year, decreasing = TRUE), ] # Confirms ordered by decreasing year
  pct_change <- -diff(x$Value)/x$Value[-1] * 100 # Gets percent change in profit from preceding year
  data.frame(year = x$YEAR[-length(x$YEAR)], pct_change = pct_change) # Returns data frame
}
```

code for the ggplot:

```
ggplot(Enrolment)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=Value),stat="identity", fill="cyan")+
  geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=year_pct_change),stat="identity",color="red",size=2)+,
       x="Year",y="Student Count")
```

it just throws me an error

> Error in `f()`: ! Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic
> aesthetic(s): y = year_pct_change.  Did you mistype the name of a data
> column or forget to add after_stat()? Run `rlang::last_error()` to see
> where the error occurred.

Any suggestions on how to add a percent difference line to my bar graph? I'm aiming to have something like this..

[graph needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOBfP.png)

Comment: The function returns a df with columns `year` (lower case) and `pct_change`, not `year_pct_change`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
    
year_pct_change <- function(x) {
  x[order(x$Year, decreasing = FALSE), ]
  x <- x |> mutate(year_pct_change = 100*((Value - lag(Value))/lag(Value)))
}
Enrolment <- year_pct_change(Enrolment)

ggplot(Enrolment)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=Value),stat="identity", fill="cyan") +
  geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=year_pct_change),stat="identity", color="red", size=2)
```

A couple of changes to the function.

1. Decreasing now FALSE.
2. New formula for % change (to match lengths of arguments and calc % (as pointed out by Rui).
3. Last line of your function unneeded now.

As there is only one y axis, you are unlikely to have the % change and Value with similar ranges.

There was a fragment at the end of your ggplot2 call that I left out: x="Year",y="Student Count"